Firebase Functions deploy failed
I am developing an Firebase Functions.
I've been following along with the following official documentation (HERE)
However, I am getting an error when deploying the functions.
> firebase deploy --only functions

Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: 
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './v2/firestore' is not defined by "exports" in /{my-repo}/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/package.json

I didn't modify any codes.
I just followed the instructions in the official guide.
My index.js is just:
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and triggers.
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");
const {onDocumentCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

initializeApp();

exports.newuser = onDocumentCreated("/users/{userId}", (event) => {
    const user = event.data.data();
    console.log("new user: " + user);
});

Here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^12.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


What should I do???
There is no longer any mention of it in the official documentation.
What am I missing?

I honestly don't even know what I did.
I tried this and that for hours.
Then I thought I had fixed that error, but now I'm getting another one.
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /{my-repo}/functions (82.74 KB) for uploading
i  functions: ensuring required API run.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API eventarc.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API run.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API storage.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: generating the service identity for pubsub.googleapis.com...
i  functions: generating the service identity for eventarc.googleapis.com...
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: creating Node.js 16 function newuser(us-central1)...
⚠  functions: HTTP Error: 400, Validation failed for trigger projects/{my-app}/locations/us-central1/triggers/newuser-168978: The request was invalid: generic::invalid_argument: Database '(default)' does not exist in region 'us-central1'. Did you mean region 'nam5'?. See 'gcloud firestore https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/databases/list to list all Firestore databases under the project.
⚠  functions: failed to create function projects/{my-app}/locations/us-central1/functions/newuser
Failed to create function projects/{my-app}/locations/us-central1/functions/newuser

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    newuser(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
⚠  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/{my-app}/us/gcf


The Firestore region is “nam5”.
However, when I try to deploy Functions to “us-central1”, the error log seems to say that the database is not found.
So I tried specifying the region as “nam5” directly in Functions.
But it still doesn't work.
const {setGlobalOptions} = require("firebase-functions/v2");

setGlobalOptions({ region: 'nam5' });


Have you tried reinstalling the Node packages? Also, does this error occur while deploying the functions or running in emulators?

on deploying the functions, and now I faced another error...

Can you please share completed code from your file, the region where you are trying to deploy your functions to and share your Firestore instance's region as well? A screenshot from Firebase console would help.

I edited, the code that's all. Can I choose a region when deploying a function?
We don't have a separate region selection.

my firestore region is "nam5"

I tried creating my default DB in another region that us-central1 but was not able to replicate this. Would you be able to run firebase deploy --only functions --debug and maybe share complete logs?

I think that my firestore region is "nam5", and functions is tring to deploy on the "us-central1". So the functions cannot find "us-central1".

The function's region should be independent of Firestore region. Can you try updating firebase-tools to latest version, re-install dependencies and if your Firestore does not have any data, try deleting and recreating it? Alternatively, you can try creating a new Firestore instance and test it with that?

my firebase-tools's version is 11.16.1. I already tried to delete firestore database, and re-created. but it's same

The latest version of firebase-tools is 13.x.x. I tried to update "npm install -g firebase-tools" but anything doesn't changed. so I think it is already latest. I remove firebase and reinstall and it works!
